# how to set max value for any column in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

In my user's table, there is the column naming as `daily_otp_count` data type is an `integer(daily_otp_count  integer)`

I want to set the max limit of that column to be `10`, and at `12:00 am` that value should be reset to `0`.

Here's my table:

```
 Table "public.users"

             Column             |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default
--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
  name_as_in_pan                | character varying(50)       |           |          |
 login_fail_timestamp           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 **daily_otp_count              | integer                     |           |          | 0**
```

Comment: The max value can be ensured through a check constraint. But resetting a value depending on some point in time needs some code that is a run a cron job (or something similar)

Comment: Please describe when this column is modified.

Answer (score 1):

It may archive on server side logic,
but if you want some db only solution.
then you can apply DB Constraint and Procedure(If you want to store logic).

check these out

- Postgresql Constraint: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html
- PostgreSQL Procedure: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html

### Example

#### Constraint

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (  -- or alter existing table
    ... 

    daily_otp_count numeric CONSTRAINT otp_max_limit CHECK (daily_otp_count <= 10)
);
```

#### Procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_user_otp_count_as_0()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
  UPDATE public.users
  SET daily_otp_count = 0;
END;
```

```sql
CALL update_user_otp_count_as_0()
```

> Even you don't use some backend server.
> You need to call this procedure from some scheduler like crontab.

> You can use `UPDATE` statement without procedures.
> I didn't mention on this answer, i thought you already knew.

Comment: Why do you use a procedure for such a simple update?

Comment: I don't use procedure, I thought questioner already knew about `update` statement, I think `update` is definitely better is most cases.